# Get percent of mixed colors in php

Tags: php, image

I'm working on application that I need to detect the percent of mixed colors in image.
How can I do it in PHP?
This is a code can get the name of colors(RGB) but there isn't any percent of mixed colors.

```
    <?php

function colorPalette($imageFile, $numColors, $granularity = 5)
{
   $granularity = max(1, abs((int)$granularity));
   $colors = array();
   $size = @getimagesize($imageFile);
   if($size === false)
   {
      user_error("Unable to get image size data");
      return false;
   }
   $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);
   if(!$img)
   {
      user_error("Unable to open image file");
      return false;
   }
   for($x = 0; $x < $size[0]; $x += $granularity)
   {
      for($y = 0; $y < $size[1]; $y += $granularity)
      {
         $thisColor = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
         $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, $thisColor);
         $red = round(round(($rgb['red'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
         $green = round(round(($rgb['green'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
         $blue = round(round(($rgb['blue'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
         $thisRGB = sprintf('%02X%02X%02X', $red, $green, $blue);
         if(array_key_exists($thisRGB, $colors))
         {
            $colors[$thisRGB]++;
         }
         else
         {
            $colors[$thisRGB] = 1;
         }
      }
   }
   arsort($colors);
   return array_slice(array_keys($colors), 0, $numColors);
}
// sample usage:
$palette = colorPalette('te.jpg', 10, 4);
echo "<table>\n";
foreach($palette as $color)
{
   echo "<tr><td style='background-color:#$color;width:2em;'>&nbsp;</td><td>#$color</td></tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a percentage of how many time a specific color appears in a picture, use something like that :

```
$sum = array_sum($palette);
foreach($palette as $color => $count)
{
   echo "<tr><td style='background-color:#$color;width:2em;'>&nbsp;</td><td>#$color (".(($count / $sum) * 100).")</td></tr>\n";
}
```

And replace

```
return array_slice(array_keys($colors), 0, $numColors);
```

By

```
 return array_slice($colors, 0, $numColors, true);
```

Comment: It didn't work probably. It can't show the color of it.and how can i write an if for each color?http://webthink.ir/go/iron.php

Comment: Ok, sorry, you needed to remove that `array_keys` too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can i add if for each color? Like if $red > %70 {echo "red picture";}

Comment: That's a different question. Please upvote and validate this answer, and then feel free to ask another question, with just relevant data and code.

Comment: Thanks. I validated the answer but I can't vote up my points aren't enough.

Answer (score 2):

Red green and blue can range from 0 to 0xFF (255). Knowning that :

```
$red = round(round(($rgb['red'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
$green = round(round(($rgb['green'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
$blue = round(round(($rgb['blue'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 

$percentRed = ($red / 0xFF) * 100;
$percentGreen = ($green / 0xFF) * 100;
$percentBlue = ($blue / 0xFF) * 100;
```

Comment: No , I mean like this #000000 20% that use in image,

Comment: O_o ? You want to know how many time a specific color is used in your image ?